# detalle al colocar un texto en un tag a, en la versión móvil de un header de pagina wordpress

Tags: javascript, html

la web esta en WordPress y tiene dos paginas  (una para la vista en pc y otra para la vista en móvil) que son trabajadas con el tema drFury, hice un cambio en el header de pc colocando una etiqueta
A,  `<a class="letramun" id="txtMunicipio"></a>` al cual le asigno el valor a través de una función JS

```
function textoDeMunicipio(){
    let tm = document.getElementById("municipio").value;
    let rt = document.getElementById("txtMunicipio");
    rt.text=tm;
}
```

ahora bien esto funciona bien en la versión de pc,
pero cuando hago esto mismo en la pagina del movil entonces **NO muestra** el valor,

hice un alert de tm  `alert(tm)` antes de `rt.text=tm` y muestra el valor correcto en tm.

Me puden indicar que otra forma puedo probar

he hecho las siguientes sin obtener el resultado

```
function textoDeMunicipio(){
    ...
    rt.innerHtml=tm;
    rt=tm;
    rt.html=tm;
}
```

quizás estoy obviando algo simple ...

***actualización***: hice pruebas como sugiere @masterguru con asignación de un texto y con las opciones predescritas no funciona.

Aquí rehago la función con la opción sugerida por Andrés que si funcionó

```
function textoDeMunicipio(){
    let tm = document.getElementById("municipio").value;
    let rt = document.getElementById("txtMunicipio");
    rt.textContent=tm;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a saco, harcodeando un valor, a ver si sale... es decir, `rt.text = "texto"` para ir delimitando el problema

Comment: saludos @masterguru no muestra bajo esa opcion, aunque con la opción `rt.textContent` si logró hacerlo, sigo sin saber a que se debe que no funcione ni innerHTML ni text.

Comment: Es porque escribes mal`innerHtml`, pues es `innerHTML`, y lo del `text` ha sido confusión mia también, pues no existe en javascript puro, sino en jquery. En javascript puro es textContent tal com ya te han indicado en la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: ok lo pruebo listo, gracias ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para pasar un valor o dato como texto legible de una etiqueta puedes usar lo siguiente:

rt.textContent = tm;

Comment: gracias Andrés por la sugerencia